# Python: Guardar solución de sympy en variables. Algebra lineal

Tags: python, numpy, matriz, sympy

Quiero guardar la solución dada por `sympy.solve_linear_system` de un sistema lineal de ecuaciones contenido en una matriz.

Por ejemplo, del matriz 2x2 dada por:
`[[1, 2], [0,0]]`  –>   `sympy` me da como solución: `{a: -2*b}`

Lo cual es correcto. Sin embargo, me gustaría saber si el valor de `"a"` de la solución dada la puedo guardar en alguna variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usted tiene:

```
from sympy import Matrix, solve_linear_system
from sympy.abc import a, b

system = Matrix(((1, 2), (0, 0)))
```

Reemplazar la última línea:

```
result = solve_linear_system(system, a, b)
```

Finalmente:

```
your_variable_a = result[a]
```

El valor de `your_variable_a` es `2`.